# Median of aggregated data

Tags: python, pandas

I have aggregated a dataframe like so:

`x_mined_median = df[(df.Confirmed == True) & (df.Type == "Mined")].groupby(['dat']).median()`

The (shortened) result is this:

```
            Confirmed      Amount
dat
2017-09-01       True  836.202740
2017-09-03       True  650.958904
2017-09-04       True  150.076712
2017-09-07       True  445.928767
2017-09-08       True  382.439041
2017-09-10       True  401.145205
```

Is there a way to get the median of the `Amount` column? (A median of the median?)

Comment: Does `x_mined_median = df[(df.Confirmed == True) & (df.Type == "Mined")].groupby(['dat']).median().Amount.median()` get what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Select column `Amount` and get `median`:

```
x_mined_median = df[(df.Confirmed == True) & (df.Type == "Mined")].groupby(['dat']).median()

a = x_mined_median['Amount'].median()
```

Alternative solution:

```
x_mined_median = (df.loc[(df.Confirmed == True) & (df.Type == "Mined"), 'Amount']
                   .groupby(df['dat']).median())

a = x_mined_median.median()
```